# MYSQL join on multiple criteria not working

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query which uses `LEFT JOIN` with multiple criteria to fetch the data. However, the query does not return any data when I use more than one `AND` clause in the conditions.

Eg:

```
LEFT JOIN tblName 
  on x.ABC=y.ABC 
 AND x.MNO="AnyValue" 
 AND x.UserId=1
```

does not return any data.

However when I remove the last `AND` clause (i.e `LEFT JOIN tblName on x.ABC=y.ABC AND x.MNO="AnyValue"`), it gives me wrong result. But yes it atleast return some data.

Let me know how to add multiple conditions to get the query working.

I want to get results using the above first condition, i.e `LEFT JOIN tblName on x.ABC=y.ABC AND x.MNO="AnyValue" AND x.UserId=1`

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: The aliases `x` and `y` are not defined so this condition should not work.

Comment: It seems to me like you're mixing up join and where clauses. Are you sure MNO and UserId are supposed to be in the join and not the where clause?

Comment: That code fragment alone cannot cause that behaviour (as a left join cannot reduce the number of results coming from the left table, just extend it). From the fact *that* it shows this behaviour we can conclude that you are using `tblName` in your `where` condition or in another join. However, we obviously cannot tell you how to fix a part of your query that we cannot see. So please add your full query (as part of what you need to add anyway, see strawberrys comment).

Answer (score 0):

Your `AND ...` criteria needs to be in the `WHERE` part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets make sure you understand what a LEFT JOIN is.  Try to think of it this way.  The left side is how I think in the sequential order of the FROM clause.  You read left-to-right, so the first table is my LEFT side which is what I ALWAYS want.  The right side (next table in the query) is optional, but if it exists, great, I have more detail.

So take a scenario of people and orders. I want a list of all people.  But if they have an order, thats even better.

```
select 
      P.LastName,
      O.OrderID,
      O.OrderDate
   from 
      People P
         LEFT JOIN Order O
            on P.PersonID = O.PersonID
```

This will do just that.  Show all people and IF they have an order, that comes along for the ride. If they have multiple orders, it will show a row for ALL orders they had.

Now, expand on criteria to the next table.  Lets say I only wanted to show orders since 2018.  That would become part of the LEFT JOIN "ON" clause because I only care about orders portion of the requirement.

```
     LEFT JOIN Order O
        on P.PersonID = O.PersonID 
        AND O.OrderDate >= '2018-01-01'
```

I would still get ALL people, but only order info will show for those with an order date on/after Jan 1, 2018.

Now, if you only cared about ONLY PEOPLE who HAD ORDERS AND the orders were on after 2018, that would basically eliminate the need for a LEFT JOIN and become a standard (INNER) JOIN

```
    JOIN Order O
       on P.PersonID = O.PersonID 
       AND O.OrderDate >= '2018-01-01'
```

JOIN Implies the record in the ORDER side table MUST be found

So in your scenario, where is your "x" and "y" alias name coming from. Completely unclear given the context, but hopefully the above clarification will help you resolve your query.  If not, update it with more detail and clarification what you are trying to get out of it.